# i want to give price range from this query result give me a correct query

Tags: mysql

i want to give price range from this query result give me a correct query

```
SELECT id,tableid,category,price,actualprice,image,title,website,description 
FROM tt_1 
where 
       title like 'Home Appliances%' or 
       image like 'Home Appliances%' or 
       category like 'Home Appliances%' or 
       site_master_url like 'Home Appliances%' or 
       website like 'Home Appliances%'
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Hint: Use AND and some parenthesis to ensure correct operator precedence (SQL uses the same rules as most languages)

Comment: The question isn't clear. Please try to give us a better explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Question unclear.
I believe this is what you want.To specify a range in mysql use BETWEEN

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE price BETWEEN lower AND upper;
```

Answer (score 1):

I will keep the same logic you have there (I think you should be using AND not OR if you are filtering data but you  would know better what you need) this will fetch price between 100-1000:

```
SELECT id,tableid,category,price,actualprice,image,title,website,description FROM tt_1 where title like 'Home Appliances%' or image like 'Home Appliances%' or category like 'Home Appliances%' or site_master_url like 'Home Appliances%' or website like 'Home Appliances%' or (price > 100 AND price < 1000)
```

Comment: What about operator precedence? This will give incorrect results

Comment: He is using OR instead of AND, I merely followed his logic (which was not part of the question)

PS: I edited one AND and made it an or (following his logic again)

Comment: this will check the price range only for the original condition website like 'Home Appliances%'. Search the internet "operator precedence" for Java, MySQL, .net, whatever and see what it means...

Answer (score 1):

Does no-one in the other answers understand [operator precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/operator-precedence.html)?

```
SELECT id,tableid,category,price,actualprice,image,title,website,description 
FROM tt_1 
where 
    (
       title like 'Home Appliances%' or 
       image like 'Home Appliances%' or 
       category like 'Home Appliances%' or 
       site_master_url like 'Home Appliances%' or 
       website like 'Home Appliances%' 
    )
    AND
    price BETWEEN @LowerBound AND @UpperBound;
```

Last line could be this too (parenthesis for clarity):

```
    AND
    (price >= @LowerBound AND price <= @UpperBound)
```

Comment: select * from (selet * from table where product_name like '%lux'..) where price >'1000'...i need like this sub query man

Comment: @Vinoth Kumar: You don't *need* a subquery? Why do you think you need one?

Answer (score 0):

Question is not cleared. I think you want to concat price range with this query. Please try with it and let me know. If your price is an integer then remove the quote from the digit.

```
SELECT id,tableid,category,price,actualprice,image,title,website,description 
FROM tt_1 
where 
       title like 'Home Appliances%' or 
       image like 'Home Appliances%' or 
       category like 'Home Appliances%' or 
       site_master_url like 'Home Appliances%' or 
       website like 'Home Appliances%' AND 
       price between 'STARTING_RANGE' AND 'ENDING_RANGE'
```

Comment: What about operator precedence? This will give incorrect results

Comment: Can your describe more your problem? Question is not clear to every one

Comment: did you try it? I think AND operator will works well, because every result checks that is it in between this price range or not.

Comment: this will check the price range *only* for the original condition `website like 'Home Appliances%'`. Search the internet "operator precedence" for Java, MySQL, .net, whatever and see what it means...

Comment: select * from (selet * from table where product_name like '%lux'..) where price >'1000'...i need like this sub query man –